# Syntax error in create aggregate

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.5

Trying to create an aggregate function:

```
create aggregate min (my_type) (
    sfunc = least,
    stype = my_type
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "least"
LINE 2:     sfunc = least,
                    ^
```

What am I missing?

[Although the manual calls `least` a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

> The GREATEST and LEAST functions select the largest or smallest value from a list of any number of expressions.

I can not find it:

```
\dfS least
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: FWIW, relevant mailing list post: http://postgresql.nabble.com/greatest-cannot-be-used-as-sfunc-for-CREATE-AGGREGATE-td5760879.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEAST` and `GREATEST` are not real functions; internally they are parsed as `MinMaxExpr` (see `src/include/nodes/primnodes.h`).

You could achieve what you want with a generic function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_least(anyelement, anyelement) RETURNS anyelement
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT
   AS 'SELECT LEAST($1, $2)';
```

(thanks to Erwin Brandstetter for the `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` and the idea to use `LEAST`.)

Then you can create your aggregate as

```
CREATE AGGREGATE min(my_type) (sfunc = my_least, stype = my_type);
```

This will only work if there are comparison functions for `my_type`, otherwise you have to come up with a different `my_least` function.

Answer (score 4):

Like `CASE`, `COALESCE` and `NULLIF`, `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are listed in the chapter [**Conditional Expressions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html). These SQL constructs are not implemented as functions .. like [@Laurenz provided](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) in the meantime.

The manual advises:

> **Tip:** If your needs go beyond the capabilities of these conditional
>   expressions, you might want to consider writing a stored procedure in
>   a more expressive programming language.

The terminology is a bit off here as well, since Postgres does not support true "stored procedures", just functions. (Which is why there is an [open TODO item "Implement stored procedures"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Server-Side_Languages).)

This manual page might be sharpened to avoid confusion ...

@Laurenz also provided an example. I would just use `LEAST` in the function to get identical functionality:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_least(anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT LEAST($1, $2)';
```

Do ***not*** make it `STRICT`, that would be incorrect. `LEAST(1, NULL)` returns `1` and not `NULL`.

Even if `STRICT` was correct, I would not use it, because it can prevent function inlining.

Note that this function is limited to exactly two parameters while `LEAST` takes *any* number of parameters. You might overload the function to cover 3, 4 etc. input parameters. Or you could write a `VARIADIC` function for up to 100 parameters.

Comment: To define an aggregate you need a function with two arguments, so a `VARIADIC` function woudn't help. Your other comments are improvements though; I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Good point. `VARIADIC` isn't meant for the aggregate. Just to remind the reader that the provided function cannot replace `LEAST` completely.